# Is Quartz2D or OpenGL more appropriate in my situation

Tags: ios, opengl-es, quartz-graphics

I'm planning on developing a 2D game.It's a traffic control game with many different entities -lanes with variety of complexities, pedestrians,bike riders,cars with different privileges and off course traffic lights, etc. Although it's going to be 2D I want it to be as smooth as possible. The objects will mostly not be as realistic - a pedestrian, for example, will more like a cartoon personage than a real man-  but the flow of the game should be natural. I'm having a little difficulty in making a decision as to whether to use Quartz or OpenGL. I read lots of threads in SO but I still need some more guidance. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For the performance view, OpenGL will be the best. Cocos2d [a link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) is a very good framework, you can put images on canvas with very good performance.

I haven't use GLKit (from iOS5), but you can put OpenGL view in the UIKit, that will be good if you still would like to draw using core graphics, you can layer the UIKit and OpenGL.

I personally recommends Kobold2d: http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKSITE/Home because it comes with many sample projects, you can start changing from.